# I have a problem in the output PDF margins

Tags: formatting, margins

I have a problem in latex template of Circuits, Systems, and Signal Processing journal the output file has not equal margins from left and right, and has a large margin from bottom of the page.
I added a line in template

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\pdfpagewidth-2in}
```

but it still has problem
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We need more information on the documentclass etc. I guess,if you use `\documentclass[oneside]{....}` the margins should be the same

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `svjour3`is not on CTAN, I assume

Comment: what means (svjour3is not on CTAN)?

Comment: @abdelwaha: It means, that not everybody has access to that class file, most of us here use TeXLive or MikTeX, which uses the CTAN network for packages and classes

Comment: The user manual of svjour3 does not say anything about equal margins, so this most probably not wanted by the publisher at all

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry I dont know what I do? I want to add that the template itself has this problem without any modification static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX.zip

Comment: @ChristianHupfer do you mean that I send the file as it is and the editor will adjust it?

Answer (score 2):

This will probably provide equally distributed left/right margins, remove the `showframe` option from the `geometry` package to remove the frame as well.

Most probably, the editor of the journal will reject it, as the class `svjour3` does not provide means for onesided documents.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage[verbose,showframe,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,marginpar=0pt,marginparsep=0pt]{geometry}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \begin{document}
    \blindtext[10]
    \end{document}
```

[image]